# How to get Youtube API notifications when a user subscribes and unsubscribes?

Tags: youtube, notifications, youtube-api, subscribe, unsubscribe

I can't find anything in the API about this, I want to setup my own database of youtube subscribers and update it automatically in real time. Is this possible without polling for and parsing email notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
youtube.subscriptions.list
```

You need to poll this web service directly,  but it will return all your subscribers in a list if you set the "mySubscribers" variable to True.

More info: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list

You can then code a way to find new users and update your local database.